# Selecting various values from an event

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I have got these 3 tables below, i want to list all athletes who won Gold

```
Athletes
    +------------+-----------------+
    | athletesID | athletesName    |
    +------------+-----------------+
    | jg         | justin gatlin   |
    | ms         | maria sharapova |
    | ub         | usain bolt      |
    | vw         | venus williams  |
    +------------+-----------------+

events
    +---------+-----------+---------------------+
    | eventID | eventName | athletes_athletesID |
    +---------+-----------+---------------------+
    | ev1     | tennis    | ms                  |
    | ev1     | tennis    | vw                  |
    | ev2     | mens 100m | jg                  |
    | ev2     | mens 100m | ub                  |
    +---------+-----------+---------------------+
results

    +-----------+--------+----------------+----------------------------+
    | resultsID | Medal  | events_eventID | events_athletes_athletesID |
    +-----------+--------+----------------+----------------------------+
    | results1  | silver | ev1            | ms                         |
    | results1  | Gold   | ev1            | vw                         |
    | results2  | silver | ev2            | jg                         |
    | results2  | Gold   | ev2            | ub                         |
    +-----------+--------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

I have used this code below so far but this lists all the silver medalists as having won Gold

```
SELECT 
    athletesID, athletesName, medal
FROM
    myoly.athletes
        JOIN
    myoly.events ON athletes.athletesID = events.athletes_athletesID
        JOIN
    myoly.results ON myoly.events.eventID = myoly.results.events_eventID
WHERE
    medal = 'gold';
```

How can I list all athletes who won Gold only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.athletesID, 
    a.athletesName, 
    r.medal
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN athletes a
ON a.athletesID  = r.events_athletes_athletesID 
WHERE r.medal = 'Gold';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove your `WHERE medal = 'gold'` and look at your results, it should give you a clue about the problem.  This is often the best way to troubleshoot.

Anyway, you need to join `results` to `athletes` on `athleteID` instead of `eventID`.  This is because you're concerned with which *athletes won gold* not which *events had a gold medal*.

```
SELECT     a.athletesID, 
           a.athletesName, 
           r.medal
FROM       athletes a
INNER JOIN results r ON a.athletesID  = r.events_athletes_athletesID 
WHERE      r.medal = 'Gold'
```